# How cdk/cloudformation understand which subnet is PRIVATE OR PUBLIC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have three subnets in AWS.

One is public because it has internet-gateway

And other two are not.

However when cdk synth, there comes template `cdk.context.json`

It judges every three subnets are `Public`

However other two are `Isolated` in fact(without NAT gateway and public IP)

Why cdk think they are `Public`??

```
  "vpc-provider:account=678100XXXXXX:filter.vpc-id=vpc-0867d6797e62dd78b:region=ap-northeast-1:returnAsymmetricSubnets=true": {
    "vpcId": "vpc-0867d6797e62dd78b",
    "vpcCidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/24",
    "availabilityZones": [],
    "subnetGroups": [
      {
        "name": "Public",
        "type": "Public",
        "subnets": [
          {
            "subnetId": "subnet-0b5985476dee1f20c",
            "cidr": "10.0.0.0/25",
            "availabilityZone": "ap-northeast-1c",
            "routeTableId": "rtb-02a749d8d4415bbfb"
          },
          {
            "subnetId": "subnet-0fdd37150bfff91f0",
            "cidr": "10.0.0.128/26",
            "availabilityZone": "ap-northeast-1c",
            "routeTableId": "rtb-02a749d8d4415bbfb"
          },
          {
            "subnetId": "subnet-085c85398f27adbfd",
            "cidr": "10.0.0.192/26",
            "availabilityZone": "ap-northeast-1d",
            "routeTableId": "rtb-02a749d8d4415bbfb"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends on the route tables. You have to check the routes in the subets's tables.

Comment: Thank you , I recheck the route table setting and solved.

Comment: No problem. I added an answer with some extra clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether a subnet is public or private is **determined by its route tables** only. Public subnets will have route tables to the **internet gateway**, whereas private subnets will not. Instead private subnets may have routes to NAT gateways, but this still does not make them public subnets.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was my careless mistake ,but It could be useful to understand the reason clearly.

Comment: I accepted this answer to the question. Although i'm not so sure now. We have two subnets in the Prod VPC which we've double checked have routes to an IGW. The CDK only finds one (although it finds both in our DEV stack). I've double checked the subnet config - definitely different AZ's. I tried looking for the source code - ended up in the `ImportedSubnet` class, and couldn't see the logic?